# SoapUI Request method for SOAP request

Tags: soapui

I set up a small project in `SoapUI` to test a 3rd party webservice.
The Request view states it's doing a `GET` request. Is that right? Should it not be a `POST` request?

What is the HTTP method a SOAP request should use?
Is it possible in `SoapUI` to set the method?
Doea `SoapUI` use the `GET` in the first place, as it's displayed.

[image: HTTP-Request]

Comment: Please have a read through [ask]. As it is, this question makes no sense.

Comment: Question makes sense to me.  It's importing a wsdl and creating default requests with the request method set to GET instead of POST.  Why is that?  Is SoapUI broken?

I'm having the same issue.